# Use of Min aggregation on SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

[image: Pivot]

Based of min run I want to use pivot to convert rows to column. Please assist.

Attached the screenshot of problem.

Comment: pivoting is very spesific to DBMS. What DBMS product are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

A stored function(or procedure) might be created in order to create a SQL for Dynamic Pivoting, and the result set is loaded into a variable of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` where determine firstly the properly concatenated list of columns by using `LISTAGG()` function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_player_results RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( rn||' AS "Col'||rn||'"',',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn)
    INTO v_cols
    FROM
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player ORDER BY run) AS rn
       FROM tab t 
    );  

  v_sql :=' SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT t.*,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY player ORDER BY run) AS rn
                      FROM tab t)
              PIVOT 
              (
               MAX(run) AS "Run", MAX(year) AS "Year"  FOR rn IN ( '|| v_cols ||' )
              )';  

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

And then invoke

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_player_results;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to get the result set.